# How can I keep the connecton to the database alive in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, connections, pgadmin-4

I am constantly seeing this message:

```
ERROR: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

And this popup:

```
Connection Warning

The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
Do you want to continue and establish a new session?
```

How do I keep connections open for query tabs? I just want to keep it alive until I close the tab.

Comment: Look in the db server's log file to see what it thinks is happening.

Comment: What is the version of both db and pgadmin4?